# Centering content inside a div with no fixed width or height

Tags: html, css

Altough, this might look a lot like many posts already existing, I couldn't find a solution to this.

I have the following HTML :

```
<div class="outer-zone">
    <div>
        Outer zone.
    </div>
    <div class="inner-zone">
        Inner zone here...
    </div>
</div>
```

and the corresponding classes, look like this :

```
.outer-zone {
    background-color : navy;
    color : whitesmoke;
    width : 90%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.inner-zone {
    background-color : deepskyblue;
    color : navy;
    width : 75%;
    height : 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have the `outer-zone` div, centered (vertically and horizontally) in the page, and the `inner-div`, centered in the outer div.

All I have found so far is how to align contents within a div with fixed height. I'd like to keep these divs with those % widths and heights.

Result so far, looks like this :

(Drag the picture a bit to notice the bottom blank space)

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you're going to need a fixed pixel, not a percentage (I just did this at work on friday, couldn't find a pecentage work around that's simple)

Comment: I think @RUJordan is correct. margin-left:auto requires a fixed width.

Comment: It is already horizontally centered, my problem is actually vertical centering.

Comment: You must use "flex box" or CSS+JS. Flex box here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I've updated with the visual result.

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick:

You need to wrap your content a div with `display:table` and height/width to 50% and  90%.
Then set your `.outer-zone` to `display:table-cell; vartical-align:middle`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tVJ3U/39/)

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="outer-zone">
            <div>
                Outer zone.
            </div>
            <div class="inner-zone">
                Inner zone here...
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.page{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.wrap{
    width:90%;
    height:50%;
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.outer-zone {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color : navy;
    color : whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.inner-zone {
    background-color : deepskyblue;
    color : navy;
    width : 75%;
    height : 40%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @chadocat : The outer div no longer respects width 90% and height 50%.

Comment: @Vasile Marian Fălămaș then you need to set the width 90% and height 50% to the wrap element http://jsfiddle.net/tVJ3U/22/ @ Ricardo Arruda why use jquery when css can do the job perfect?

Comment: Because of the wrap, the vertical alignment is no longer applied. I'll have to see how this is done as well. Outer div needs also to be centered on the page.

Comment: ok didn't understand you also wanted the .outer-zone to be center, I'll update my answer.

Comment: EDITED. Everything is centered now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PU3Rw/

CSS:

```
html,body{display:table;width:100%;height:100%;}

.main{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```